# How do you use TCP in Adventurer's League Season 8?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, treasure

In Dungeons And Dragons Adventurer's League Season 8 instead of Gold you get Treasure Checkpoints (TCP). During some sessions the DM has announced we've unlocked a particular item.

I then also understand that TCP can only be used on items from, or below, the tier you earned the points.

For example TCP earned in Tier 2 can be used on Tier 2 and Tier 1 eligible items, but not Tier 3 items. Thus as I just hit level 5 I should use my TCP for something.

My question is are the items that were unlocked during play the only things I can use it on? If not, where do I find a complete list of tier 1 items to spend the TCP on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your tier 1 Treasure Checkpoints can be used in the following ways:

- As you state, they can be used to purchase magic items from tables A, B,
  C and F that you have unlocked during play.
- They can be used to purchase tier 1 magic items from the "evergreen" unlock
  list, which can be found in the *Adventurers League Content Catalog* v8.09 (ALCC),
  p. 4.
- Until season 8 ends, they can be used to purchase tier 1 magic items from the
  season 8 unlock list, found in ALCC p. 52.
- They can be converted to gold at a rate of 50 gp per 1 TCP, as stated
  in ALCC p. 4

The ALCC, along with other Adventurers League documents, can be found [here](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack).